# Browser stops working because of embeded website but only when showing an icon

Tags: html

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8"/> 
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="mm.jpg" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16"> 
    <title>Startseite</title>
    <style>

    body {
        background-image: url(Startseite.jpg);
        background-size: 1300px;
        background-position: 50% 0%;
        font-family: Arial Nova;
    }

    p {
        color: white;
        margin: 12px 0px 12px 16px;
        font-size: 130%;
    }

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0px 12px 0px 12px;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #165da3;
        border: 1px solid #04436c;
        opacity: 0.9;
    }

    li {
        float: left;
    }

    li a {
        display: inline-block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 18px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    li a:hover {
        text-shadow: 5px 5px #1b4f72;
        background-color: #083f77;
    }

    li a:active {
        background-color: #043c61;
        color: #eaf3fa;
    }

    .embeded-content {
        padding: 12px;
        width: 98.4%;
        height: 570px;
    }

    .show {
        display: block;
    }

    .hide {
        display: none;
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Google new Tab</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="loadPage()" href="#">Google</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="d" class="hide">
    <object class="embeded-content" type="text/html" data="https://google.com/"></object>
</div>

<script>

var state = false;

function loadPage() {
    if (state) {
        document.getElementById('d').classList.add('hide');
        document.getElementById('d').classList.remove('show');
        state = false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('d').classList.add('show');
        document.getElementById('d').classList.remove('hide');
        state = true;
    }   
}

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

I use

```
<object class="embeded-content" type="text/html" data="https://google.com/"></object>
```

to embed a website into my page (I know that I can not use Google when embeding it, this is just an example).
When clicking on "Google", it opens Google in the page. With a second click, it vanishes again, as expected.

Now the problem is:
When I use an icon (Line 5), and then click multiple times on "Google", my whole browser stops working for about 10 seconds.
Without the icon, it works just fine.
I have the same problem with iframes.

Does anyone know why this is the case? And how can I use the icon without it causing this problem?

Comment: Your icon is `.jpg`, but the type is `image/gif`. Maybe thats the problem?

Comment: Yes this could be it. Thank you!